# how to show a div content after every 2 minutes?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show following code on after every 2 minutes on rightside corner of my page

```
#notification
  = link_to "Tomorrow there are <span>#{@current_user.reminders.size}</span> events".html_safe,events_path
```

---

I tried following code but its not working the way i want...

```
function notification()
{  
   $("#notification").show("slow").delay(800).fadeout(400);
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: That first snippet looks quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a function at an interval of 2 minutes use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // do something here
}, 120000); // 2 minutes = 120000 miliseconds
```

EDIT:

From your comment I'm guessing you want something more like this:

```
function notify() {
    // show and delay for 60000 (1 minute) before hiding
    $("#notification").show("slow").delay(60000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // show again after 120000 (2 minutes)
        setTimeout(notify, 120000);
    });
}

notify();
```

Notice the callback function on the `fadeOut` method. That tells it to call the `notify` function again after 2 minutes.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwtkh/4/
​

Comment: I used following... function notification(){  
      setInterval(function() {
       $('#notification').show()}, 12000); 
    } but its not wat i want after every 2 minuts..i mean it should b shown for say 1 min then after it should b hidden for 2 min den again shown...

Comment: @NJF You should have asked for that then. You say it doesn't work, in what way does it not work?